# What does "You couldn't stretch a leg here without poking a poet in the ass," mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In the below passage, what does Jalil's comment mean?

> Jalil never called Mariam this name. Jalil said she was his little flower. He was fond of sitting her on his lap and telling her stories, like the time he told her that Herat, the city where Mariam was born, in 1959, had once been the cradle of Persian culture, the home of writers, painters, and Sufis.
>
> "You couldn't stretch a leg here without poking a poet in the ass," he laughed.

Comment: _Please_ give the source of literary quotations that you ask questions about.

Comment: This appears to be from *A Thousand Splendid Suns*

Comment: Will you either drop, or explain the value of "Jalil never called Mariam this name. Jalil said she was his little flower. He was fond of sitting her on his lap and telling her stories, like the time he told her that Herat, the city where Mariam was born, in 1959, had once been the cradle of Persian culture, the home of writers, painters, and Sufis"?

Does that leave "You couldn't stretch a leg here without poking a poet in the ass," or what, please?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The writer is trying to say that there were lots of poets around. Wherever you were, whatever direction you were facing, if you stretched your leg you would hit a poet. They were all around.

I've heard variations of this. Like, "You couldn't throw a rock from a train without hitting an X".

The details of stretching a leg versus, say, swinging your arm, and of hitting a poet in the rear end versus in the stomach, are irrelevant to the point.

Comment: Yeah it's not a common phrasing but the general formula is simply "you couldn't [verb] a [noun] without hitting [common thing]."

Comment: A popular similar variation of this without the [common thing] is "Not Enough Room to Swing a Cat"

Comment: Or "you can't swing a dead cat without hitting `<some common thing>`"

Comment: I think its worth mentioning that saying "you couldn't throw a rock without hitting a poet" would seem like a boring/plain phrase so by whereas by making it crass the character says the same thing but maintains their personality while saying it.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal I suppose that's a matter of taste. Personally I find the "stick in the a**" phrasing vulgar and distasteful. I grasp that others find it amusing and clever. I suppose that's an issue that comes up routinely when you use vulgarity: Some will find it distasteful or even offensive, others will find it amusing.

Comment: I wouldn't even say tasteful but rather "this character would be out of character saying something NOT vulgar" so they need to find a vulgar way to say the same thing.